# How to protect PDFs on server

Tags: security, pdf

I have a site, where the user uploads PDF files, with very secret data. The PDFs mustn't be accessible from anywhere except in the site, which is protected as well as I could.

Can any of you tell me how to prevent direct access to the PDFs, so if someone enters the pdf link in his browser - he will get an error?

Edit:

Let me make it clear. The documents are shown inside the site, for authorized users after entering a username and a password. They can add, edit, delete and read the site content - including the PDF files. The PDFs are shown in the site inside an iframe element.

The PHP files and pages are are secured, and if someone who didn't logged in to the site tries to enter them - they see an error. I've done it with my PHP code. But I can't secure PDFs the same way.

Now, I want to protect the files, so they can be viewed only for the users, and if someone reaches somehow a direct link to a PDF - he won't be able to see it.

What kind of lines do I have to add to my .htaccess to protect the PDFs? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If nobody should be able to download these files, why not put them anywhere outside the document root?

Comment: If you want to control the access further (eg: store in a database which user has access to which files), you need to write some code for that. How do to this depends on the rest of your application, but as you haven't shared any details, this cannot be answered properly

Comment: No! The logged in users can see the files inside an iframe in the site. I want that the files can be viewed only in that iframe. If someone enters the direct link to the file in the browser - they will get an error. 
How can I control the access to the file itself on the server?

Comment: That won't work. The server cannot detect whether you are loading the file using an iframe or not. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

The website could be entirely login based therefore only accessible to the user when they have logged in. If another user was to try to access the page they should be prompted for a username and password before gaining access.

Comment: Thanks but I can't protect a direct link to a PDF through a server code. the entire site IS login based. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the technology / webserver in question you have a couple of options.

For e.g.:

If running an hosted Apache service you could specify an .htaccess file in your website (although this is not ideal, due to some performance loss)
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Look at my edited answer.